# Numerical integration

Tags: numerical-methods

Determine coefficients $A_k ; k=1,2,3,4$ in the following quadratic formula 
$$\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)dx=A_1f(-1)+A_2f(1)+A_3f'(-1)+A_4f(1)+R$$
such that it has the maximum possible algebraic degree of accuracy. Evaluate an error, and using the obtained formula evaluate the following integral:

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin xdx.$$

Could someone explain in details how to solve these types of problems?

Comment: Substitute $f(x)$ for $1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4$. Put $R=0$ in all cases. You get a system of 4 linear equations in the four unknowns $A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4$.

Comment: @Mlazhinka Shung Gronzalez LeWy , Could you give a complete answer?

Comment: Is the $A_4f(1)$ missing a prime?

Comment: @Mlazhinka Shung Gronzalez LeWy, No.

Comment: Ok, then we might need to hope for less. Call $A_2f(1)+A_4f(1) = Bf(1)$. And for any solution for $B$ $A_2,A_4$ can take any values that add up to $B$.

Comment: @Mlazhinka Shung Gronzalez LeWy, Ok, could you give a complete answer now?

Comment: yes, one sec. Grocery shopping first, if you haven't got an answer I will post one.

Comment: Ok. The problem is likely badly copied but well ... To solve it as if the quadrature were $A_1f(-1)+Bf(1)+A_3f'(-1)$ we need the equation to be satisfied for $f(x)=1,x,x^2,...,x^n$, with $R=0$ for $n$ as large as possible. Replace those $f$ and you get many equations. So, you need to take the first $n$ equations with $n$ as large as possible such that there are solutions. For that largest $n$, solve the system and find one solution for$A_1,B,A_3$. Finally Evaluate $A_1\sin(-1)+B\sin(1)+A_3\cos(-1)$.

Comment: @Mlazhinka Shung Gronzalez LeWy, Could you please give a full answer?